# Magento css changes not showing - magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, scss

I have made some **css** changes to my `custom.css` file and it's well uploaded to server but i can't see my changes on frontend.

Comment: what do you mean by css are updating in server ?

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command and then check your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your css is loaded, your website -> right click and select view page source or just press ctrl+u. There you'll find your file.css. Check if it is showing this file.css and the right url. Click on it, see if it is loading ok.

It should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.exemple.com/skin/frontend/package/theme/css/file.css" media="all" />
```

For this problem to happen, There are three reasons I know of:

1.) There might be an issue because of System Cache. Clean the cache from the backend or go to `magentoroot/var/` and delete the contents of the cache and session folder.

2.) There can be issue with the file permission of your css File. In this case just type the following command in terminal, `sudo chmod 777 -R /magentoroot/`

3.) Lastly, there could be something wrong with the url in your core_config_data table of your database, which I think you have already checked.

4.) Flush your navigator cache : `Ctrl+Shift+R`

Comment: All css files are loaded in css but not loading in pub/static/frontend/  i tried to clear files in var_preprocessed and static-content:deploy its wont work . To make it happen everytime i have to delete the .css file from pub/static/frontend and clear cache.